# session var is lost when changing page

Tags: php, session

I've made a custom login on my website and I manage the logged in users via a $_SESSION var. My problem append after the login action. On the next page I control the login information and if everything is correct I save the connected user id in `$_SESSION['currentUser'] = serialize($successUser);`.

But now if I navigate to another page, I'm not logged in anymore... Like if the $_session var wasn't correctly saved...

Part of my problem was on my server configuration. I corrected it by changing the session.save_path in php.ini.

But now my problem is still present in one of my web application. So there is a coding error somewhere. Can anyone help me to find it out ? Here is my code:

Every page starts with :

```
<?php
include('includes.php');

//page header
include("header.php");?>
<header class="sheet">
  <h1>About...</h1>
</header>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...
```

includes.php:

```
<?php //includes.php
session_start();

//includes classes
require_once 'classes/User.php';
require_once 'classes/Event.php';
require_once 'classes/Address.php';
....

//Globale vars
$currentUser = (isset($_SESSION['currentUser']))?unserialize($_SESSION['currentUser']):NULL;

//Includes services
require_once 'services/SrvCRUD.php';
require_once 'services/SrvCRUD_User.php';
...
require_once 'services/SrvFct_User.php';
require_once 'services/SrvFct_Address.php';
require_once 'services/SrvFct_Event.php';
...

//pages actions
include('page_actions.php');
```

header.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>...</title></head><body>
...
```

Thanks for your help.

P.S : I searched a lot on the Internet about my problem and I've already checked current errors like a white space before the `<?php session_start()...`.
If I `var_dump` my $_SESSION, it shows that my variable doesn't exist on the next page...

EDIT:
As this problem seems to be a configuration problem, here is the session part of my php.ini

```
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /home/users/***complete-path-censored***/tmp
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 1
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 4
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="
```

Comment: What happens when you login but refresh the same page?  Can you redirect to itself in the form action and set the session then var_dump() it to see if it's set?

Comment: Check the settings in [Session] in your php.ini... in general, HTTP is stateless so it needs to pass the session identification along with every new request. PHP uses either cookies or rewriting URL and adding GET argument to all links (both variables are named PHPSESSID by default). If your app is loosing the session both this methods fail. Your question is quite wide to just answer it exactly.

Comment: On a side note, why are you serializing data that you are putting into the session? That just generates extra work for you to unserialize it when you want to access it, and is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @AdRock In fact, the login action Post the request to the same page which will check the login info and save the session. At this step, the session var is OK if I var_dump its value.

Comment: @KamilŠrot, I'll check that as soon as I have access to my server.

Comment: @CBroe I have to serialize it because I store an object, not just a simple string

Comment: Is there anything in the other files you include that could be messing up the sessions like in your SrvFct_User.php?

Comment: SrvFct... and SrvCRUD... are just classes for services which will manage the DB. They don't interact with session vars, forms or others. But I have someting new... The same pages are working successfully on my local XAMPP... So it must be something wrong with the php.ini on my PROD server. As @KamilŠrot said...

Comment: @Miam84 Are you absolutely sure, the session.save_path is accessible and writable by the apache user? Are there any files (session data) in this folder?

Comment: Ok... as CBroe said I was serializing the data. I was interested to know if it's really necessary to serialize object too, so I made a search. I learned that, the sessions automatically serialize the object but you have to declare your classes before the session_start() to unserialize it correctly. I've made this simple change to improve my code, and for a reason that I can't understand, this change solved my problem too... No idea why. I just removed the un-/serialize methods and declared the model before the session start... If somebody knows why ?!! 
Thanks all for your help and advices!

Comment: If this procedure you did solved your problem, please post it as an answer and mark it as the answer. You are allowed to do this. We can discuss the reason why it worked directly on the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... as CBroe said I was serializing the data. I was interested to know if it's really necessary to serialize object too, so I made a search. I learned that, the sessions automatically serialize the object but you have to declare your classes before the session_start() to unserialize it correctly. I've made this simple change to improve my code, and for a reason that I can't understand, this change solved my problem too... No idea why. I just removed the un-/serialize methods and declared the model before the session start... If somebody knows why, I would be interested to be informed :) ?!!
Thank you all for your help and advices